# mysql: charset for relation tables

Tags: mysql

what is the best charset in term of performance for multi multi relation tables, the ones only have whole bunches of ids referencing to other tables' primary ids. Or it does not matter just using anything you like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character sets only matter if you have any string columns. If your table only contains numeric foreign keys, just don't specify a charset when creating the table.